# Finding unknown word in string

Tags: c

I'm building a simple menu and came up with a doubt: the user is gonna have some defined commands, for example, an entry would be "compact image < filename >.jpeg". How can I get the filename and extension from the middle of the string?

Comment: This might be where you define a grammar and parse the command (lex, yacc, etc).  Alternatively, you use an ad hoc parsing system and recognize that `compact` is a keyword, the `image` is a valid qualifier for `compact`, and that it is followed by a filename.  You design your ad hoc parsing code to deal with this.  It's not particularly difficult; it's not very exciting, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is an actual example of the string that you need to get the file name from you can:

1. Split the string defining the separator as a space
2. Take the last position of the split and take everything up to the fileExtension or Period

Answer (score 0):

Use **strstr** to find instances of "needle" in "haystack" - it will return an index to the ".", for example, and you can construct new strings containing the file-name and extension using this index.

Hope this helps!